# Query to remove all non-digit but only keep last period/dot

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Struggle to design a regular expression to filter field value from `varchar2` to `number`, so that it can remove all non-digit and only left the last period in the string, so that

```
"about 1,000.00" return 1000.00 or 1000
"3,000,000.000" return 300000.000 or 3000000
"3.000.000.000" return return 3000000.000 or 3000000
"a^*3^%*(C4.5d*9" return 34.59
```

Any method just change the string into accurate convertible string that can be converted by `to_number()`

I use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(field_value, '[^0-9\.]+', '') from dual;
```

but can't resolve the 3rd case....

Comment: Is there always at least one decimal point that would be considered the last decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, assuming there is one decimal character.  The value you are working with is a string so I think of the decimal that we want to keep as a separator of the string and split it into 2 parts based on that.  The first part is all characters leading up to but not including the last decimal, the second part is the last decimal and all characters after it.  Then apply the replace, getting rid of everything that is not a number from the first part, and everything that is not a number or a decimal from the second part, then concatenate them together.  Needs more testing with varied inputs but you get the idea.  All these regular expressions are kind of expensive though so I doubt this will be the fastest solution.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'about 1,000.00'  from dual union
  select '3,000,000.000'   from dual union
  select '3.000.000.000'   from dual union
  select 'a^*3^%*(C4.5d*9' from dual
)
select str original,
       regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '^(.*)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '[^0-9]+', '') ||
       regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '.*(\..*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '[^0-9\.]+', '') Converted
from tbl;

SQL> /

ORIGINAL        CONVERTED
--------------- ---------------
3,000,000.000   3000000.000
3.000.000.000   3000000.000
a^*3^%*(C4.5d*9 34.59
about 1,000.00  1000.00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the regex in oracle are somewhat limited I don't think it's possible only using regexp_replace. You could do a workaround like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN last_dot < 2 THEN digits_and_dots
    ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTR(digits_and_dots, 1, last_dot - 1), '.') ||
                 SUBSTR(digits_and_dots, last_dot)
  END
FROM (
  SELECT
    INSTR(digits_and_dots, '.', -1) last_dot,
    digits_and_dots
  FROM (
    SELECT
      REGEXP_REPLACE(field_value, '[^0-9\.]+', '') digits_and_dots
    FROM DUAL
  ) t
) o
```

Comment: thanks, thumbs up for the quick reply an this works fine, however if use in an update query then it is slightly limited in 11g, because the table identifier has to pass in the deeper layer of the query, which only supported in 12c. Still a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way is as follows:

```
select regexp_substr('a^*3^%*(C4.5d*9s','\d+\.\d+') from dual;
```

or

```
select regexp_replace('a^*3^%*(C4.5d*9s', '[^0.0-9]', '') from dual;
```